# Accessing Mongo from within mocha tests for Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mocha.js

I have a node file for some simple data access and it appears to work in my manual tests. That code is here:

```
(function() {

var mongojs = require("mongojs");
var uuid = require("node-uuid");

var db = mongojs("tradeAssistant", ["tickers"]);

function insertTicker(tickerSymbol) {
    if (tickerSymbol) {
        var ticker = db.tickers.findOne({
            symbol: tickerSymbol
        });

        if (!ticker) {
            console.log("inserting " + tickerSymbol);

            db.tickers.insert({
                _id: uuid.v4(),
                symbol: tickerSymbol,
                isNew: true
            }, function(err, data) {
                console.log("back from db.tickers.insert");
            });
        }
    }
}

exports.addTickers = function addTickers(tickers, callback) {
    if (tickers) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tickers.length; i++) {
            insertTicker(tickers[i].toUpperCase());
        }
    }
    callback(null, null);
};

exports.fetchTickers = function fetchTickers(query, callback) {
    var results = [];
    if (!query) {
        query = {}
    };

    db.tickers.find(query, function(err, docs) {
        if (!err) {
            for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
                results.push(docs[i]);
            }
        }
        callback(err, results);
    });
}
})();
```

As I said, that code appears to work. I was attempting to build some mocha integration tests and they didn't work. As I started to drill down and debug, I found that mongo doesn't work at all from inside Mocha. Not really sure what I'm missing.

```
(function() {
var mongojs = require("mongojs");
var should = require("should");
var db = mongojs("tradeAssistant", ["tickers"]);

//var tickerData = require("../../mongoDataAccess/tickersAccess");

describe("tickerAccess.addTickers()", function() {
    it("test 1", function() {

        db.tickers.insert({
            symbol: "DIA",
            isNew: true
        }, function(err, data) {
            console.log("hello world");
        });
    });
});
})();
```

I'm new to Node, so if you see other things that need "fixing," please don't be shy. More importantly, however, I would appreciate any help anyone could provide on why mongo doesn't appear to work from mocha. I get no error; there's nothing in the mongo log file, and my console.log() never gets called.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Vic

Comment: How are you running the test file?

Comment: great question. From the command-line, i'm using mocha --recursive. That's it. The test "passes" according to mocha, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're ignoring the async nature of your test. You can add a callback to your test like this:

```
describe("tickerAccess.addTickers()", function() {
  it("test 1", function(done) {
    db.tickers.insert({
        symbol: "DIA",
        isNew: true
    }, function(err, data) {
        console.log("hello world");
        done()
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Got it. You and lxe got it right . . . I put the done in the wrong function parameter list. Thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up the `it` handler to take the `done` parameter, and call `done()` in the callback of the mongo operation to let mocha know that the async operation has finished:

```
describe("tickerAccess.addTickers()", function() {
    it("test 1", function(done) {

        db.tickers.insert({
            symbol: "DIA",
            isNew: true
        }, function(err, data) {
            console.log("hello world");
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

More on how to run asynchronous code in mocha [here](http://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However, that doesn't work. Also, the console.log() doesn't happen either, so I don't think that callback function is ever being executed. Mongo must be failing in some way, but I'm not sure how or why.